# Translate message attachment in bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework

I was trying the multi-language chat bot in bot framework. https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/17.multilingual-bot.
I was successful in translating ordinary message with no attachment. But I'm having a problem with attachment like herocard or suggestedcard.

```
var reply = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply();
var card = new HeroCard();

card.Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
{
new CardAction() { Title = "1. All lights are green.", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "All lights are green." },
new CardAction() { Title = "2. DSL light is OFF/Red/Blinking Green.", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "DSL light is OFF/Red/Blinking Green." },
new CardAction() { Title = "3. Internet light is OFF/Red/Amber or blinking red and green.", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "Internet light is OFF/Red/Amber or blinking red and green." },
new CardAction() { Title = "4. Power light is OFF/Red/Amber or blinking.", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "Power light is OFF/Red/Amber or blinking." },
};
reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>() { card.ToAttachment() };
reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.List;

var options = new PromptOptions()
                {
                    Prompt = reply, 
                };

await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
```

Thanks!

Comment: the text inside the attachment is not translating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if there are any attachments. I have some middleware that sets the speak on message and use the following code:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.Text))
{
    if (message.Attachments[0].Content is HeroCard attachment)
    {
        message.Speak = TextToSpeechHelper.ConvertTextToSpeechText(attachment.Text);
    }
}
else
{
    message.Speak = TextToSpeechHelper.ConvertTextToSpeechText(message.Text);
}
```

You'd have to adjust it to set the text and translate.

Below is a full example of what my middleware is. Keep in mind this middleware sets the speak to the text and sets the input hint.

```
public class TextToSpeechMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<string> ignoreList;

    public TextToSpeechMiddleware(string speakIgnore)
    {
        ignoreList = GetSpeakIgnore(speakIgnore);
    }

    public Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        turnContext.OnSendActivities(OnSendActivities);
        turnContext.OnUpdateActivity(OnUpdateActivity);

        return next(cancellationToken);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetSpeakIgnore(string value)
    {
        string[] ignoreList = value.Split(';');

        return ignoreList.Select(i => i.Trim())
                         .Where(i => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i));
    }

    private Task<ResourceResponse> OnUpdateActivity(ITurnContext turnContext, Activity activity, Func<Task<ResourceResponse>> next)
    {
        ConvertTextToSpeech(activity);
        return next();
    }

    private Task<ResourceResponse[]> OnSendActivities(ITurnContext turnContext, List<Activity> activities, Func<Task<ResourceResponse[]>> next)
    {
        foreach (Activity currentActivity in activities.Where(a => a.Type == ActivityTypes.Message))
        {
            ConvertTextToSpeech(currentActivity);
        }

        return next();
    }

    private void ConvertTextToSpeech(Activity message)
    {
        Activity initialMessage = message;

        try
        {
            if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                bool ignoredSpeak = false;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.Speak))
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.Text))
                    {
                        if (message.Attachments[0].Content is HeroCard attachment)
                        {
                            message.Speak = TextToSpeechHelper.ConvertTextToSpeechText(attachment.Text);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        message.Speak = TextToSpeechHelper.ConvertTextToSpeechText(message.Text);
                    }

                    message.Speak = message.Speak.Trim();

                    if (ignoreList.Where(i => message.Speak.ToLower().StartsWith(i.ToLower())).Count() != 0)
                    {
                        message.Speak = null;
                        ignoredSpeak = true;
                    }
                }
                else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message.Speak))
                {
                    message.Speak = " ";
                }

                if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.Speak) && (message.Speak.EndsWith("?") || message.Speak.StartsWith("Is this correct?")))
                     || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.Text) && message.Text.EndsWith("?"))
                     || ignoredSpeak)
                {
                    message.InputHint = InputHints.ExpectingInput;
                }

                // IOs won't work with expecting input
                if (message.Recipient.Name.EndsWith(":ios"))
                {
                    message.InputHint = InputHints.AcceptingInput;
                }
            }

            // Logic needed to increase speech speed.
            // if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.Speak))
            // {
            //    message.Speak = @"<speak version='1.0' " + "xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis' xml:lang='en-GB'><prosody rate=\"1.5\">" + message.Speak + "</prosody></speak>";
            // }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            message = initialMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I have the sample of your middleware?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the full middleware class I use.